# the image P' of a point P under a rotation. (Vector)

Tags: java

I have this question for computer science and I have had to make a `Vector3` class and a `Quaternion` class. This is the last method I have to implement and I have no idea what the question means.

> A class method image that finds the image P' of a point P under a
> rotation. The header of the method is
>
> public static Vector3 image (Vector3 p, Vector3 u, double theta)
>
> Here p is a vector whose components are the coordinates of the point
> P, u is a vector giving the direction of the axis of the rotation, and
> theta is the angle, in radians, through which the rotation is to take
> place. The vector returned by the method has components that are the
> coordinates of the image point P'.

Comment: You will want to rotate point p by angle theta around the axis of u.... what confuses you? This is more of a geometry question than a Java question.

Comment: Are you familiar with linear algebra? Will save you a lot of headache to take the matrix form of rotations. http://inside.mines.edu/~gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/

Comment: Read about the relation of Quaternions to rotations in space (for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).